# Minecraft pocket edition save and quit

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was playing minecraft pocket edition and quit and saved my game before I left, because I didn't die, however when I logged back in I was somehow in my house. What happened to my stuff I had on me and how do I get back to where I was?

Comment: Do you think that someone else at home may have logged in on your device, played in your world with your account, died, and logged out before you logged back in? Also, where were you when you saved and quit?

Answer (score 1):

Every time instead of saving and quitting I just close the game so it loads everything that happens.

This includes the mobs and deaths so that could be part of your problem.

When this happens I make sure I know my location Just in case.

One another thing you could do is build a box around you to stand in.

I hope this helps :)